# It's Not 2015 Anymore!

Tags: string, code-golf

### The Rules

- Each submission must be a full program or a function.
- The program must take all instances of the string `2015` from the input (1 string), replace it with `<s>2015</s>*` (with <s> or <strike>). At the end, if there has been at least one `2015` in the string, you must add a newline and this string: `*2016. I'm a year early!`
- The program must not write anything to STDERR.
- The input will not contain `<s>2015</s>` or `<strike>2015</strike>`.

  Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested.
- Submissions are scored in *bytes*, in an appropriate (pre-existing) encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8. Some languages, like [Folders](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Folders), are a bit tricky to score - if in doubt, please ask on [Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins

### Examples

**Input:**

```
Hello! The date is 2015-12-24.
```

**Output:**

```
Hello! The date is 2015*-12-24.
*2016. I'm a year early!
```

**Input:**

```
foo bar baz quux
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar baz quux
```

**Input:**

```
12320151203205120151294201511271823
```

**Output:**

```
1232015*120320512015*12942015*11271823
*2016. I'm a year early!
```

**Input:**

```
 Hello. The year is 2015...
2015.5...
```

**Output:**

```
 Hello. The year is 2015*...
2015*.5...
*2016. I'm a year early!
```

### The Snippet

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalogue from the answers a) as a leaderboard and b) as a list of winners per language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=68372,OVERRIDE_USER=45162;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?([\d.]+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Can we use `<strike>`?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would allow you to make it shorter.

Comment: @BlockCoder1392 It might. `"asdf".strike()` is javascript.

Comment: Hmm... sure. I'll add it to the post

Comment: Can the input contain `<s>2015</s>*`?

Comment: No. The input will not contain `<s>2015</s>` or `<strike>2015</strike>`.

Comment: @downvoters what is wrong with this challenge?

Comment: I find the challenge boring. It's a find-replace followed by a conditional concatenated string. Also, I don't like when functions are disallowed for no particular reason.

Comment: @xnor ... To quote NBZ, "Because there are not enough simple code-golf challenges"

Comment: Yes, but a challenge can be simple without being straightforward. Replacement or regex is a built-in in most langs. It means that's likely just the way to do it.

Comment: Can we have any trailing whitespace?

Comment: Not everyone agrees with @NBZ on that. And there are certainly more than enough trivial questions. If you post questions which have a negative score in the sandbox, don't be surprised to see them downvoted.

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ No trailing whitespace.

Comment: Will the input have newlines

Comment: Your code has to accept new lines.

Comment: instead of "replace it with `<s>2015</s`> (with <s> or <strike>)and put an asterisk to the right of it" you could just say "replace it with `<s>2015</s>*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç┼↕+∙n7↔Qq┼╩↓╣ÇÖú];ⁿX£╞bëi⌐ñ▼Z♀φ6╛(<
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=87c5122bf96e371d5171c5ca19b98099a35d3bfc589cc6628969a9a41f5a0ced36be283c&i=Hello%21+The+date+is+2015-12-24.%0A12320151203205120151294201511271823%0A+Hello.+The+year+is+2015...%0A2015.5...%0A%0Afoo+bar+baz+quux&a=1&m=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
_               push all of standard input
2015X           push 2015 and store it in the x register
$/c             split string on "2015", and copy the result
"<s>`x</s>*"*P  join with "<s>2015</s>*" and print
D!C             stop executing if split resulted in more than 1 element
'*p             print "*" without newline
|Xp             increment x register and print without newline
                print unterminated compressed literal ". I'm a year early!"
`Q_RUWZ)O-C!
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=_+++++++++++++%09push+all+of+standard+input%0A2015X+++++++++%09push+2015+and+store+it+in+the+x+register%0A%24%2Fc+++++++++++%09split+string+on+%222015%22,+and+copy+the+result%0A%22%3Cs%3E%60x%3C%2Fs%3E*%22*P%09join+with+%22%3Cs%3E2015%3C%2Fs%3E*%22+and+print%0AD%21C+++++++++++%09stop+executing+if+split+resulted+in+more+than+1+element%0A%27*p+++++++++++%09print+%22*%22+without+newline%0A%7CXp+++++++++++%09increment+x+register+and+print+without+newline%0A++++++++++++++%09print+unterminated+compressed+literal+%22.+I%27m+a+year+early%21%22%0A%60Q_RUWZ%29O-C%21&i=Hello%21+The+date+is+2015-12-24.%0A12320151203205120151294201511271823%0A+Hello.+The+year+is+2015...%0A2015.5...%0A%0Afoo+bar+baz+quux&m=1)

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>84 76</s> 75 bytes

```
s=>(q=s.replace(/2015/g,"<s>$&</s>*"))+(s<q?`
*2016. I'm a year early!`:"")
```

This is pretty well golfed for JavaScript imo.

---

This works by taking the input and replacing all instances of `2015` with `<s>$&</s>*` where `$&` is the value matched, but in this case, that's always `2015`. Then, if the input is different from `q`, it'll add the `*2016...` string, otherwise, It'll add a blank string (nothing).

Comment: I think you can do ``(q!=s&&`\n*2016. I'm a year early!`)``

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That seems to add "false" to the string when the condition is false :(

Comment: Oh, dangit. That's bad :P

Comment: Very interesting. Never knew about `$&` or any of the other [special replacement patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 69 bytes

```rb
$><<gets.gsub(/2015/,'<s>\&</s>*')
puts"*2016. I'm a year early!"if$&
```

Answer (score 4):

## Jolf, 60 bytes

Two parts, again.

```
oHρi"2015"+pd"s'$&'*"
oH                    set H
  ρi"2015"             to input string, replaced all 2015 with
           pd"s'$&'    $& crossed out. (pd is an apply tag function)
          +        *" append an asterisk

    v-- unprintable
+H|&?=Hi+S"*2016. I\'m a year early!'"
+H|&?=Hi                            '" add ↓ to H if H != i; otherwise add empty string ('")
        +S"*2016. I\'m a year early!'  a newline plus that string
                                       implicit printing
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=b0jPgWkiMjAxNSIrcGQicyckJicqIitIfCZ_PUhpK1MiKjIwMTYuIElcJ20gYSB5ZWFyIGVhcmx5ISci&input=SXQncyAyMDE1ISBIQUhBIQ) Bonus points for actually crossing out the text and conforming to the output examples? :3

Comment: Technically against the rules. +1.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 97 bytes

```python
a=raw_input();b=a.replace('2015','<s>2015</s>*');print a;
if a!=b:print"*2016. I'm a year early!"
```

This takes input from stdin, replaces any instances of 2015 with a strike, and prints the 2016  message if the two strings don't match.

Comment: couldn't you use `a<b` instead of `a!=b`?

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 98 bytes

```
a="2015";StringReplace[#,a->"<s>2015</s>*"]<>If[#~StringCount~a>0,"
*2016. I'm a year early!",""]&
```

Once again, Mathematica's string processing uses many bytes...

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
I-
:z"2015""<s>2015</s>*"z." ytµbðï«»±é¢þnl¶Vû
```

[Test Suite](http://localhost:8000/?code=I-%0A%3Az%222015%22%22%3Cs%3E2015%3C%2Fs%3E%2a%22z.%22+y%01%C2%95t%C2%B5b%C3%B0%18%C3%AF%C2%AB%C2%BB%C2%B1%C3%A9%C2%A2%C3%BEnl%02%C2%B6V%C3%BB&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Hello%21+The+date+is+2015-12-24.%0Afoo+bar+baz+quux%0A12320151203205120151294201511271823&debug=1).

Answer (score 2):

## , 49 chars / 93 bytes

```
a=ïę ḟ*ṁ,`<s>$&</s>*”)+(a≠ï?ɘƂ联Ӏఈ쁬Πā␎䁛␐줄쁰ꖈᲠ䉠耀#:⬯
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=12320151203205120151294201511271823&code=a%3D%C3%AF%C4%99%20%E1%B8%9F*%E1%B9%81%2C%60%3Cs%3E%24%26%3C%2Fs%3E*%E2%80%9D%29%2B%28a%E2%89%A0%C3%AF%3F%C9%98%C6%82%E8%81%94%D3%80%E0%B0%88%EC%81%AC%CE%A0%C4%81%E2%90%8E%E4%81%9B%E2%90%90%EC%A4%84%EF%80%94%EC%81%B0%EA%96%88%E1%B2%A0%E4%89%A0%E8%80%80%23%3A%E2%AC%AF)</kbd>

Really straightforward. `a=ïę ḟ*ṁ,'<s>$&</s>*”)` nests all instances of 2015 (represented here as the result of 31*65) in strikethrough tags. Then, append the last string ('compressed' here) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 59 bytes

```
(q=xg2015,"<s>$&</s>*"))+(x<q?`
*2016. I'm a year early!`:u
```

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22(q%3Dxg2015,%5C%22%3Cs%3E$%26%3C%2Fs%3E*%5C%22))%2B(x%3Cq%3F%60%5Cn*2016.%20I'm%20a%20year%20early!%60:u%22&inputs=%5B%22Foo%202015%20Foo%202015%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false%7D)

### Explanation

```
(q=        // Assign `q` to...
   xg      // input.replace
     2015  // 2015 with.
     "..." // The string
)) +       // Add to..

(x<q?      // If the input is different from replacement
     "..." // Add string to the end
    :u     // Otherwise empty string
```

Comment: Downvote reason? This answer is perfectly valid, wth?

Comment: They'll always downvote downgoat!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 :( Maybe [Upgoat](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48036/upgoat) is having better luck

Comment: How legal are sockpuppet accounts?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I don't use them for evil, >:)  just chatbots so it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

### Japt, 51 bytes

```
Y=Ur2015"<s>$&</s>*")¥U?U:Y+`
*2016. I'm a ye e§!
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=WT1VcjIwMTUiPHM+JCY8L3M+KiIppVU/VTpZK2AKKjIwMTYuIEknbSBhIHllhyBlh6ch&input=IjEyMzIwMTUxMjAzMjA1MTIwMTUxMjk0MjAxNTExMjcxODIzIg==)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
Ž7ç©åi®®"<s>ÿ</s>*".:®>“*ÿ. I'm€…‚Œ‰€!“»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVcAqP9vc2FiaWX//8W9N8OnwqnDpWnCrsKuIjxzPsO/PC9zPioiLjrCrj7igJwqw78uIEknbeKCrOKApuKAmsWS4oCw4oKsIeKAnMK7//9JIGxpa2UgMjAxNSE)

*-2 thanks to Grimy*

### Explanation

```
Ž7ç©åi®®"<s>ÿ</s>*".:®>“*ÿ. I'm€…‚Œ‰€!“» Full Program
Ž7ç©                                     Pushes 2015 and copies it to the register
    å                                    Checks if 2015 occurs in the input
     i                                   If yes, do the following steps, else
                                          finish and output the input
      ®®"<s>ÿ</s>*"                      Pushes 2015 and "<s>2015</s>*"
                   .:                    Replaces all instances of 2015 by 
                                          </s>2015</s> in the input
                     ®>“*ÿ. I'm€…‚Œ‰€!“  Push "*2016. I'm a year early!"
                                       » Concatenate both strings with a newline in between
```

Comment: The `»` is not needed when there is no replacement, so you can just drop the `}` for -1.

Comment: 40: [`Ž7ç©åi®®"<s>ÿ</s>*".:®>“*ÿ. I'm€…‚Œ‰€!“»`](https://tio.run/##AVcAqP9vc2FiaWX//8W9N8OnwqnDpWnCrsKuIjxzPsO/PC9zPioiLjrCrj7igJwqw78uIEknbeKCrOKApuKAmsWS4oCw4oKsIeKAnMK7//9JIGxpa2UgMjAxNSE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://github.com/arturo-lang/arturo), <del>83</del> 79 bytes

```
$[s][r:replace s"2015""<s>2015</s>*"if r<>s['r++"\n*2016. I'm a year early!"]r]
```

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Suggested `r<>s[suffix'r"\n*2016` ~> `r<>s['r++"\n*2016`.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Please read https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/suggested-edits-reject-golfing.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I'm not sure I'm too familiar with CodeGolf posting standards, but given that I am the original author of the language (Arturo), I just found this and decided to post my own - slightly shorter - solution. :)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Nice to see you here and thank you for the golf! Here we usually suggest golfs in comments instead of editing the answer, so that, probably why you were received so harshly ;)

Comment: @xigoi Well, I guess I know now lol. In any case, great to see an Arturo example here! Needless to say, I was more than pleasantly suprised! :)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Had you "... decided to post my own - slightly shorter - solution." in form of writing a separate answer and triggered a First Post review job, I would have most likely accepted it. By editing another user's post, you alter their contribution (where the StackExchange system does not provide a convenient way to communicate with this user) and are not this post's author. Most golfing suggestions are incorporated into the post by its original author who then gives credit to the user who suggested it. Even though xigoi accepted your change, only the post's history gives you credit.

Answer (score 1):

### (f)lex, 104 bytes

File `2015.l`:

```
 int n=0;
%%
"2015" ++n+puts("<s>2015</s>*");
%%
main(){yylex();n&&puts( "*2016. I'm a year early!\n");}
```

...no trailing newline.

Build:

```
$ flex -o 2015.c 2015.l
$ gcc 2015.c -o 2015 -lfl
```

Run:

```
$ ./2015 <<<'Hello! The date is 2015-12-24.'
Hello! The date is <s>2015</s>*-12-24.
*2016. I'm a year early!
$ ./2015 <<<'foo bar baz quux'
foo bar baz quux
$ ./2015 <<<'12320151203205120151294201511271823'
123<s>2015</s>*12032051<s>2015</s>*1294<s>2015</s>*11271823
*2016. I'm a year early!
```

I ran this using `flex` and `gcc` on Debian8, but I see no reason why it should fail in other environments using `lex` and/or a different C compiler.

Comment: Note it may bail out due to integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 152 bytes

```
class A{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write(a[0].Replace("2015","<s>2015</s>*")+(a[0].Contains("2015")?"\n*2016. I'm a year early!":""));}}
```

Basic solution. Takes the string as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 57 bytes

```
2015=<s>$0</s>*@set{a;*2016. I'm a year early\!}
\Z=${a;}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema -f not-2015.gema <<< 'Hello! The date is 2015-12-24.'
Hello! The date is <s>2015</s>*-12-24.
*2016. I'm a year early!

bash-4.3$ gema -f not-2015.gema <<< 'foo bar baz quux'
foo bar baz quux

bash-4.3$ gema -f not-2015.gema <<< '12320151203205120151294201511271823'
123<s>2015</s>*12032051<s>2015</s>*1294<s>2015</s>*11271823
*2016. I'm a year early!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($n)($z=$n-replace2015,'<s>$&</s>*')+"
*2016. I'm a year early!"*($z-ne$n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwFET3/YprU6kgVFvwFZW17t2bqiWa8BIkKui3Y9u4uJnJZObklsVTVfVVpWlPkm3Xl7KS2Yjk7oi0W5IHlSpTeVZiymc@3dQxcTaTOvaoO8bI0@mcwZ5mIOGtZAX60vcAe3oc5EpT@i9CeKfpxQAOVwUX@VBwq8HwAi4CETHsI5wUBZz0/iRbuDfNy2RchKbFxVSrEeNXkVUuFnwpQlMDS2eWbn/40xljyKpxGD5D6MAhCZDjGij99j8)

Just a replace on the input and a conditional append with the 2016 line. You don't need many quotes or spaces in PowerShell either.

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwFET3/YprU6kgVFvwFZW17t2bqiWa8BIkKui3Y9u4uJnJZObklsVTVfVVpWlPkm3Xl7KS2Yjk7oi0W5IHlSpTeVZiymc@3dQxcTaTOvaoO8bI0@mcwZ5mIOGtZAX60vcAe3oc5EpT@i9CeKfpxQAOVwUX@VBwq8HwAi4CETHsI5wUBZz0/iRbuDfNy2RchKbFxVSrEeNXkVUuFnwpQlMDS2eWbn/40xljyKpxGD5D6MAhCZDjGij99j8 "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>49 45 64 61 60</s> 54 bytes

```
s`2015.+
$&¶*2016. I'm a year early!
\`2015
<s>$&</s>*
```

After numerous attempts I think this is the shortest Retina solution

---

The first line matches `2015`, the second line replaces the previous match (`2015`) with `<s>$&</s>*` where `$&` is the match's value or in this case, `2015`.

The `\` removes the trailing newline from the output. The `` ` `` starts the regex. `$` matches the end specifying we're trying to add a string to the end. The last line simply adds the string where `¶` becomes a newline. Retina uses the ISO-8859-1 encoding in which the `¶` is one byte

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=c2AyMDE1LisKJCbCtioyMDE2LiBJJ20gYSB5ZWFyIGVhcmx5IQpcYDIwMTUKPHM-JCY8L3M-Kg&input=Zm9vIDIwMTUgYmFyIAoyMDE1IGJheiAyMDE2)

Answer (score 0):

### [ROOP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ROOP), 110 bytes

```
 1I
 CW
 |%|
 V !
H
' "<s>2015</s>*"
2R !
0 #V
1 G #
5V #"\n*2016. I'm a year early!"
'| M #
 -V #

  #W
   O#
```

This uses the `R` operator to replace all occurrences of the string `2015` in the input to `<s>2015</s>*`.Then, there is a comparison -- if the input string and the new one are different, then 1 is returned. Otherwise, 0 is returned. Then, `M` repeats the string `\n*2016. I'm a year early` that many times, i.e. if there are no changes, the string is blank, otherwise, the string is `\n*2016. I'm a year early`. Then, the strings are printed and the program terminates.

Above there is a 1 which is moved to the left and then falls to the operator H, which ends the program.

Comment: It should print "*2016. I'm a year early!" only once

Comment: That's what it does.

Comment: Oh. I misinterpreted the usage of M.

Comment: Use 1 or 0, sorry, English is not my native language. Feel free to improve the text if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 80 bytes

```python
lambda x:(b:=x.replace('2015','<s>2015<s>*'))+"\n*2016. I'm a year early!"*(b>x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZBBTsMwEEX3PsV0NrHT1qqdAqWiXcOeHenCoQ41cu2QpFLCCTgBB@QiwTZcASRb73vm68szzdifvCs2TTvVu3Ky6lwdFQxbWm13A291Y9Wzpplciatskd11@6gC8oyxOZYuD@9rDg/ZGRSMWrUQrh1nmNNqP7CpaY3rKX59fvzpKR3yV28cNTCH8K2yf/G6g95D6IRSTQ376SCpfQsGjIMngvfaWj@Dx5OGo@o1mA7igEshl3LNcUGw9h6qMFal3uHtchliTcgiuoRcBUZEfbtOFPJGbGQRbYiQ8nnKT8v5zeeck8Sogo8cGCP/tCpk0zc)

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to squid*

Comment: Unless I've missed a way that this breaks it, [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##vVBBTsMwELz7Fdu9JGlTq3YKlIpyhju3JAeHOtTItYPjSgkv4AU8kI8EO/AFkHY1s7uj0e52oz9ZU@w6N7WHatLi3BwFDPtyyAfqZKfFs0zF/pDwDbtK8uSuv48swDLJVliZZSivKTwmZxAwSuEgpB4XWJcClIGhnjqnjE/x6/PjT6MySF@tMqmCFYTNKv9iZQ/eQpiEVpuq7GeCpLUOVFyvJPggtbYLeDpJOAovQfUQT1wzvuZbijnB1lpowmWNeIe3y2WIPcaLqGJ8EzBC5LfbGRm/YTteRBkizP509p//8@tPKSUzRhZ0pM4y8k@vwmz6Bg "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##vZBBTsMwEEX3PsV0NrHT1qqdAqWiXcOeHenCoQ41cu2QpFLCCTgBB@QiwTZcASRb73vm68szzdifvCs2TTvVu3Ky6lwdFQxbWm13A291Y9Wzpplciatskd11@6gC8oyxOZYuD@9rDg/ZGRSMWrUQrh1nmNNqP7CpaY3rKX59fvzpKR3yV28cNTCH8K2yf/G6g95D6IRSTQ376SCpfQsGjIMngvfaWj@Dx5OGo@o1mA7igEshl3LNcUGw9h6qMFal3uHtchliTcgiuoRcBUZEfbtOFPJGbGQRbYiQ8nnKT8v5zeeck8Sogo8cGCP/tCpk0zc "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @squid Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 53 bytes

```perl
$\="\n*2016. I'm a year early!"if s|2015|<s>$&</s>*|g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlYpJk/LyMDQTE/BUz1XIVGhMjWxSAGIcyoVlTLTFIprgJKmNTbFdipqNvrFdlo16f//GxoZg0QNjQyANIgCsS1NwLShkbmhhZHxv/yCksz8vOL/ugU5AA)

Comment: [Literal newline instead of "\n" saves a byte](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlaJS8vIwNBMT8FTPVchUaEyNbFIAYhzKhWVMtMUimuAkqY1NsV2Kmo2@sV2WjXp//8bGhmDRA2NDIA0iAKxLU3AtKGRuaGFkfG//IKSzPy84v@6BTkA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript: 62 bytes

```js
x=>x.replace('2015','<s>2015</s>')+"\n*2016. I'm a year early!"
```

Comment: I'm afraid you missed a point: “\n*2016. I'm a year early!” has to be appended only if the input contained “2015” and your code actually made a replacement. So you must not append it to “foo bar baz quux”.